# Double click event on Panel

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I saw in some source code (few days ago) that a program had a `dblclick` event or something like that on the panel.

If you look a the docs

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel

under events, there are no events for clicking.

I think I saw something like

```
ondblclick
```

and then

```
fn: function(){...}
```

Why it's not in documentation and how can I fire the `dblclick` event on the panel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to @sra answer I would say that it is possible to assign handlers to `Component`'s dom using `element` option when assigning listener:

```
var panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    // ...
    listeners: {
        dblclick: function() {
            // handle event
        },
        element: 'body'
    }
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/WrpzE/)

Answer (score 2):

The following example will work. The **[double click event](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-event-dblclick)** will get fired by the **[Ext.Element](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element)** which can be fetched after rendering from the body param of the panel. In the example I override the **[afterRender](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.util.Renderable-method-afterRender)** method cause there is no need to register a event for that. There I register a listener to the Ext.Element of the current panel.

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.panel.DCPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.dcpanel',
    initComponent: function() {

        this.callParent(arguments);
    },
    afterRender: function() {
        var me = this;
        me.body.on('dblclick', function() { alert('hit'); }, me);
        me.callParent();
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.ux.panel.DCPanel', {
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    title: 'Demo',
    html: 'this is my data',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Comment: I was thinking to give you the "correct answer" but the other one is more acceptable for my needs on this app. :)

Comment: @user1509885
That's no problem for me:)